# Disable livereload with Yeoman angular web app

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, forever, yeoman-generator-angular

I have a Yeoman web app up and running. It fails to retrieve livereload.js and can take up 21s before timing out and the page then goes on to load.

I don't even need the livereload functionality. This is a web app that is finished with development.

I use forever to start the web app. I navigate to the root folder of my app which contains my Gruntfile.js. I then run the command - forever start /usr/local/bin/grunt

What do I need to do to disable this livereload functionality?

Comment: Did you try removing the livereload configuration from your gruntfile? Alternatively, if you're running on a remote server, the port that livereload is trying to find could be blocked. Opening it will solve your timeout. We had the same issue.

Comment: I added false after each livereload: string in the gruntfile. Hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Can you post your gruntfile?

Comment: I set `livereload: false` in all instances in my Gruntfile and the page did **not** auto-refresh. On a manual refresh, the changes I made were reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable running livereload server from the grunt file. *However*, that will still load the livereload js file in website footer and result in very slow page loads.

The reload script is being added from the server side. Edit the file `server/config/express.js` and comment out the line:

```
app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
```

**Note:** You seem to have bigger problems as well. You said, the site has completed development, but livereload works which is possible only when the server is running in development mode(unless you have edited Gruntfile to that effect). What you need is `grunt serve:dist` instead of simple `grunt serve`. Running the server in dev environment is a security as well as performance problem.

**PS:** I started with a similar set up but found later that sometimes the app.js will throw an error while grunt will continue running. This will put forever useless. You shall need the grunt-forever npm module to make sure forever is monitoring the right file.